# Angular does not detect changes made from window global function

Tags: javascript, angular, events

During the work I encountered a very strange behaviour.

Here is the `link` for a similar problem: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjxzvu)

From `index.html` file I have raised some click event

```
function createClause(event) {
    Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(
      Office.CoercionType.Text,
      (asyncResult) => {
        window.sendSelectedTextCallback({selectedText: asyncResult.value});
        event.completed();
      });
  }
```

In the `app.component.ts` I'm listening to the `sendSelectedTextCallback` function.

```
(window as any).sendSelectedTextCallback = (params: any) => {
    clauseCommunicationService.addClause({name: params.selectedText});
};
```

`clauseCommunicationService.addClause` method calls `next` function for a `subject`.

In some component I'm listening for the changes.

```
this.clauseAddedSubscription = clauseCommunicationService.clauseAdded$.subscribe(
  (clause) => {
    this.clauses.push(clause);
    console.log(this.clauses);
  }
);
```

The issue i'm facing is that `console.log(this.clauses)` command shows me the list updated, but this is not reflected on the `UI`.

If I'm replacing

```
(window as any).sendSelectedTextCallback = (params: any) => {
    clauseCommunicationService.addClause({name: params.selectedText});
}
```

with

```
setTimeout(() => {
   clauseCommunicationService.addClause({name: 'helloooo'});
 }, 4000);
```

i can see that the changes are reflected on the UI.

I tried to use `ngZone` and `ChangeDetector` features but without success.

Comment: how is `this.clauses` declared?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, `public clauses: any[] = [];`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, in the `onInit` method it is initialized with something from the `server`

Comment: What does the template look like? if you are using a 3rd party tool, you might need to tell it that the data has changed and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I'm using some 3rd party tool. I have updated the `createClause` method.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, but I'm receiving the signal inside the component and I can see that the list is updated but changes are not reflected in the `UI`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, If i send the signal from some angular component instead of `index.html` script function, then also it worked

Comment: could you create a [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, yes, I have created it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjxzvu

Comment: But why are you creating a click event in `index.html`? This is out of Angular's world. Why not in `app.component.ts`?

Comment: @JeremyThille, i'm using `office.js` library and I declared some function which needs to defined in some html file.

Comment: When I click the button, I see the UI update, and the array displays fine.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, uncomment the line with `cdr.detectChanges()`.

Comment: It is uncommented.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, sorry, I mean comment it :))

Comment: Hmm... I see now...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because the button is outside of angular, so angular doesn't test for change detection on the button so when the button gets clicked it doesn't know something happened. We can add change detection to that button using a `@HostListener` [Stack Blitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dkesj).

```js
export class HelloComponent {
  public elements = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  @HostListener('window:click')
  private onWindowClick() {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  constructor(
    @Inject(CommunicationService)
    private communicationService: CommunicationService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.communicationService.elemAdded$.subscribe(elem => {
      this.elements.push(elem);
      console.log(this.elements);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for my code, but for Stackblitz

Comment: The reason is that the click event occurs on the office context and not the angular app.

Answer (score 1):

You can force angular to "refresh" and take into consideration events and things that are out of its world by using ngZone : try this

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// In the constructor, inject NgZone
constructor(private zone: NgZone) { }

// Then :
clauseCommunicationService.clauseAdded$.subscribe(
     (clause) => {
          this.zone.run(() => { // Where the magic happens
               this.clauses.push(clause);
               console.log(this.clauses);
          })
     }
 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for my code, but for Stackblitz